# Write 2 SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle11g

[image: Ex_complex is an exercise complex]

Here is my ERD. I use Oracle SQL. I need:

1) Select exercise which involves the greatest number of muscle.

2) Select top 5 exercises by number of involved muscles.

Comment: Non of the table have "number of muscle", can you suggest which table and column will give "number of muscle"?

Comment: Can you create [SQL Fiddle?](http://sqlfiddle.com/) It shouldn't be that hard to do, but I need to play a little I didn't use oracle syntax so I need to check if it's work...

Comment: include your sample data and expected output? Readd this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've written queries:
It's for first task and the second will be the same, except R < 6:

```
SELECT *
FROM exercise
WHERE exercise.ex_id = any
    (SELECT ex_id
     FROM
       (SELECT e.ex_id, dense_rank() over (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS R
        FROM muscle m, muscle_group mg, ex_complex ex_c, exercise e
        WHERE m.mgroup_id = mg.mgroup_id
          AND ex_c.mgroup_id = mg.mgroup_id
          AND ex_c.ex_id = e.ex_id
        GROUP BY e.ex_id)
     WHERE R < 2);
```